# Uncaught umbrella exception escaped

Tags: gwt, mvp, requestfactory

Please help me resolve this Umbrella exception http://pastebin.com/DACPRhbP

NewUserPresenter file :
http://pastebin.com/FZyAffu8

NewUserViewImpl file:
http://pastebin.com/i6fYwnLH

User Entity in server folder: 
http://pastebin.com/6ktwf5vp

Appcontroller:
http://pastebin.com/Kn5Wg61e

Entrypoint:
http://pastebin.com/sEHHihVu

UserProxy:http://pastebin.com/mfd67p2U

UserRequest: http://pastebin.com/JxQe77LL

To me it seems that it could be the request factory stuff I added to this project has caused these exceptions. Before that everything was alright.

Comment: Your exception seems to be cut off - can you share the whole thing? UmbrellaException means that it wraps another exception - that is the real exception and needs to be solved. The wrapping umbrella exception just means that in firing an event, one or more exceptions were caused, and are all being reported together.

Comment: Done. Please have a look now.

Comment: By putting all files on a temporary external site this question will be useless as soon as those files are gone and of no help to other people who might experience a similar problem. So please put some effort in the question by putting the specifics in the question.

Comment: It wasn't possible to put the whole exception in the question text itself. I would have done the same if it was possible. And if possible I would  change the expiry time of pastes to never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/umbrella$20exception/google-web-toolkit/aZggEeNm0Js/9qfNXleD1lwJ

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5760

Reason for exception was that there was no getter method defined for password field.